# Populate an bash array with available android devices

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to populate a global variable of type array in a bash shell script. I was using subshell in a function and i understand now that after the code executes all is lost and the global declared var wasn't set with the new value. Now i am trying a different approach but still doesn't seem to work well. This is the code:

```
declare -a arr
let i=1
function availableDevices {
    while read line #get list of devices
      do
        if [ -n "$line" ] && [ "`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`" == "device" ]
        then
          device="`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`"
          echo "Add $device"
          arr[i]="$device"
          let i=$i+1
        fi
      done < <(adb devices)
    echo "devices: ${arr[*]}"
}
```

When i call this function this error appears:

```
name.sh: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented
```

I am new to scripting and probably is self explanatory but i don't get it. HOw can the function not be implemented? Thanks

Comment: _cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented_ -- Does this give a hint?  Your shell does not support the `<(...)` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that there's actually bash, not sh, specified as hash-bang, as it seems that the message comes from using the "< <(" bashism.
Also try:    line="a b c";   set -- $line; echo 2
see whether that could have any use in your script, instead of  echo $line | awk ..., alternatively, "Here strings" are often preferred over piping output of echo. A Here string looks like this (example):
rev <<< test

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes. it's a .sh file. I am trying to get the value of the array outside the subshell and not very good at this. :)

Comment: if you're really using bash, your hash bang line must clearly say so. there's a difference between bash and sh.  sh won't execute many things bash can do. the error you get may be one of those. for example. with bash you can do  (( i++ ))  instead of    let i=$i+1 - but if your hash bang line says  #!/bin/sh, that won't work, regardless of whether your script has .sh or not appended to its name.

Comment: instead of 'arr[i]="$device"; let i=$i+1', you'd say with bash simply 'arr[i++]="$device"', another bashism not compatible with POSIX sh

Comment: and ignore my ` line="a b c"; set -- $line; echo 2` suggestion in the initial reply - as you seem to be interested in $1 and $2 only, read them into variables right away, instead of reading whole line, which then must be split again. Like:  `while read device class remainder; do ... (device is already in $device, $class may contain text "device" to identify lines with devices) ...; done < ... ` - no need for awk and subshells